# OpenGL lighting problem when rotating the camera

Tags: opengl, lighting

I draw buildings in my game world, i shade them with the following code:

```
GLfloat light_ambient[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
GLfloat light_position[] = {135.66f, 129.83f, 4.7f, 1.0f};

glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT);
```

It works nicely.

But when i start flying in the world, the lighting reacts to that as if the world was an object that is being rotated. So the lights changes when my camera angle changes.

How do i revert that rotation? so the lighting would think that i am not actually rotating the world, and then i could make my buildings have static shading which would change depending on where the sun is on the sky.

Edit: here is the rendering code:

```
int DrawGLScene()
{

    // stuff

    glLoadIdentity();

    glRotatef(XROT, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(YROT, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(ZROT, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glTranslatef(-XPOS, -YPOS, -ZPOS);

    // draw world
}
```

Comment: the problem is likely in your movement/rotation code, post that as well.

Comment: Added the rendering code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/lights.htm

See #18.050

In short, you need to make sure you're defining your light position in the right reference frame and applying the appropriate transforms each frame to keep it where you want it.

Edit:

With the removal of the fixed function pipeline in OpenGL 3.1 the code and answer here are deprecated.  The correct answer now is to pass your light position(s) into your vertex/fragment shaders and perform your shading using that position in world space. This calculation varies based on the type of lighting you're doing (PBR, phong, deferred etc).

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem arises from the fact that OpenGL Lights are specified in World Coordinates, but stored internally in Camera Coordinates. This means that once you place a light, whenever you move your camera, your light will move with it.

To fix this, simply reposition your lights whenever you move your camera.